# Python x-www-form-urlencoded POSTing: cannot find attributes

Tags: python, forms, urllib2, mechanize

Recently I came across a page which seems impossible to make POST request via python since I could not find certain attributes anywhere in the source code.

So basically here's the content from Live Http Header when manually POST to that page:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

Content-Length: 616 

form_key=VeBg0awGeGySaRYzBZc8jMwH0&secure_form_key=%21331352042042%7CsYH2EQfAK7nTIakC55PK8SQv78&blahblahblah
```

As you can see I can easily locate `form_key` but cannot find `secure_form_key` anywhere after carefully checking the source page. Where could it possibly be hidden? And how should I find it?

Comment: If it's not in a hidden form field, it's probably added by javascript.

Comment: @stranac: yeah, i understand. But I've checked all `<script>` lines and still found nothing. Would you mind checking it out please: `https://www.tumblr.com/settings`

Comment: The script on line 327 of the source dynamically adds another script, which creates the hidden input field. It seems like it could be reversed pretty easily, but if you can do this using the tumblr api, that's how you should do it.

Comment: @stranac: That line did look weird(long meaningless string!) to me from the beginning, since I'm not quite into javascript I don't really understand what it's trying to do. I've checked their API, and you can do nothing about the settings part with it. That's why I'm trying to find a way to do it myself. So would you please be specific and tell me how do I "reverse" that line?

Comment: @stranac: Thanks a lot mate! Now I see what you mean, well it's quite an interesting way to hide stuff!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to interface with tumblr, why not use the official API instead of trying to hack forms on the normal website?

Available from: http://code.google.com/p/python-tumblr/

Comment: I've checked their API and you can do nothing about the settings part with it. That's why I came out with this question. Thanks anyway!